# missing ) after argument list but [there is no opening ")"]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying for the past few hours to figure out what's going wrong here. The console says `"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"` for the last line of code. I don't see where I would be missing an opening ( that needs to be closed.

```
// TWITTER SCRIPT
!function(d,s,id){
var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
if(!d.getElementById(id)){
    js=d.createElement(s);
    js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
}}
(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');

// TEMPORARY WORKAROUND FOR MENU ISSUE
function closeDropdowns() {
$(".dropdown-toggle").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("aria-expanded", false);
    $(this).parent("li").removeClass("open");
});
};

$(document).ready(function(){

// PARALLAX
$(".entire-page").stellar();

// TOOLTIP
$(function () {
$("#item1").tooltip();
});  

$(function () {
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

// SMOOTH SCROLLING
var $root = $('html, body');
$('.navbar-nav a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
  $root.animate({
    scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
  }, 
  500, function () {
      window.location.hash = href;
  });
  return false;
});

// MY SCRIPTS

$(".contact-submit").on("click", function(){

    // TURN BOX RED FOR NO INPUT
    if ($("#message-box").val() == "") {
        $("#message-box").css("border", "2px solid red");
    } else {
        // REPLACE TEXT BOXES WITH USER INPUT ON SUBMISSION
        var name = $("#contact-text").val();
        var email = $("#contact-email").val();
        var comment = $("#message-box").val();

        $("#visible-name").html(name);
        $("#visible-email").html(email);
        $("#visible-comment").html(comment);

        $("#contact-text").hide("slow");
        $("#contact-email").hide("slow");
        $(".contact-submit").hide("slow");

        $("#message-box").hide("slow", function(){
            var thanks = ("Thanks for reaching out!");
            alert(thanks);
            console.log("Content submitted");
        });

        $(".contact-box").css("background-color", "white");
        $(".contact-box").css("padding", "2px 2%");
    };

    return false;

});

// CHARACTER COUNT MESSAGE BOX
$("#message-box").on("keyup", function(){
    console.log("Keyup happened");
    var charCount = $("#message-box").val().length;
    console.log(charCount);
    $("#char-count").html(charCount);
    $("#char-count").css("color", "white");
    if (charCount > 50) {
        $("#char-count").css("color", "red");
    } else {
        $("#char-count").css("color", "white");
    };
});

// WORK SECTION
for(var i = 0; i < works.length; ++i){
    $("#works").append("\
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-6 project'>\
            <img class='img-responsive' src='" + works[i] + "'>\
        </div>\
    ");
};

};
```

Comment: Indenting your code would help immensely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your document ready function when I remove the code. You're missing the ) before the semi colon

```
$(document).ready(function(){

}; //<-------- (it should be: "});"
```

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

The code you need to fix in your question is on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You're opening with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

And closing with:

```
};
```

You're missing a closing parenthesis. Needs to be:

```
});
```

Hence the error message.

Look at it this way, per how you currently have it: `$(document).ready(function() {};`

See how you're missing the closing `)` for `.ready()`?